# WebStorm giving TypeScript error on "??" operator

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm having issue using WebStorm with TypeScript v3.7.5. In this version, TS add the `??` operator. I'm using it in my project but WebStorm don't seem to understand it, giving an `expression expected` error. However, running the `tsc` command gives no error.

[image]
[image]

Opening the code in VSCode shows no error, so I don't think the issue come from my TS configuration.

Does anyone knows the reason and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What WebStorm version do you use? Nullish Coalescing is supported since 2019.3, please see [WEB-41494](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41494)

Comment: That seems to be the reason...  I have v2019.2 of WebStorm